# Как обратиться к ячейке stringGrid?

Tags: delphi

Как обратиться к определеной ячейке в stringGrid? Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии мышкой на ячейку происходили действия: на каждой ячейке новое действие.

Answer (score 3):

Надо при нажатии определить сначала какой номер ячейки (строка и столбец), я потом определить, что будет выполняться при нажатии:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Значение := StringGrid1.Cells[StringGrid1.Col, StringGrid1.Row];
 if StringGrid1.Col = 1 then //ткнули в ячейку второй колонки
  Действие 1
 if StringGrid1.Col = 2 then //ткнули в ячейку третьей колонки
  Действие 2

  //другой вариант

  case StringGrid1.Col of

    0 : Действие 1;

    1 : Действие 2;

    2 : Действие 3;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы ячейки были как кнопки.

Comment: Ну надо было так и написать (а не проще ли кнопок понаставить рядом и всё?).

Comment: Неопределенное количество кнопок задаваемое пользователем, но я уже сделал,с помощу MouseToCell.

    procedure TForm1.StringGrid1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    with StringGrid1 do
      if((Col=x)and(Row=y)) then Klik;
    end; 

Работает как часики

Answer (score 1):

Я однажды использовал процедуру выбора ячейки...

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean); //процедура выбора ячейки
begin
    if(StringGrid1.Cell[ACol,ARow] = "but1") then
      begin
        //ваше действие
      end;
end;
```